# Azure: Change interface addresses with iproute2 command

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine

I want to create a virtual private network in which I can manage virtual machines's interfaces with iproute2.

For example, with AZ CLI, I create two virtual machines in subnet 172.16.1.0/24, each machine has one interface:
`az network vnet create  -g test -n net --address-prefix 172.16.0.0/16 --ddos-protection false --vm-protection false`

`az network vnet subnet create -g test --vnet-name net -n subnet1 --address-prefixes 172.16.1.0/24 --network-security-group test`

`az network nic create -g test -n vm1-nic --vnet-name net --subnet subnet1 --private-ip-address 172.16.1.10 --public-ip-address vm1-pub`

`az network nic create -g test -n vm2-nic --vnet-name net --subnet subnet1 --private-ip-address 172.16.1.11 --public-ip-address vm2-pub`

`az vm create -g test -n vm1 --image rhel --size Standard_F4 --generate-ssh-keys --nics vm1-nic`

`az vm create -g test -n vm2 --image rhel --size Standard_F4 --generate-ssh-keys --nics vm2-nic`

Then I connect on vm1 with ssh, ping 172.16.1.11 should work.

It is possible to change vm's network interfaces ip addresses with iproute2 command? Like I put 10.100.0.1/24 on vm1's interface and 10.100.0.2/24 on vm2's interface with iprout2 command and I ping to 10.100.0.2 from 10.100.0.1.

I want to understand how virtual machines are connected, the connection is simulated as a wired connection which we can configure network interfaces?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the description for the static IP address [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-arm-pportal#set-ip-addresses-within-the-operating-system):

> If you manually set the private IP address within the operating
> system, make sure it matches the private IP address assigned to the
> Azure network interface. Otherwise, you can lose connectivity to the
> VM.

It means if you want to change the IP address within the VM, you need first to change the configuration of the VM NIC in Azure, then you can change the IP address within the VM using the command. If not, you can't change it. Generally, all the things of the VM are configured by Azure.